# ASP.Net Session issue in Android Default and Chrome browsers

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, session-state

I am developing an ASP.Net 4.0 website. I have used basic authentication in Login and after login a new session created.

I am facing strange issue in Android mobiles (even ICS). The Android's default browser and Chrome not allowing me to login. But Opera mini allows login.

Couldn't find any answers related to this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960832/maintaining-session-in-android-application-stay-authenticated-on-the-server-si) is a discussion about similar issue but it handled in Android.

But I need to handle in ASP.Net.

Comment: is your cookie path=/ else try changing to that

Comment: @droidhot Where to I put the cookie path?

Comment: check it in chrome by clicking inspect element if its different try setting path in asp.net side

Comment: I checked the Cookie path in chrome (Laptop) -> Resources/Cookies and it shows path = /. Any other change?

Comment: no idea that was the only problem which lead to some thing like that about which i know