# How can I select a client certificate using the same HttpClient instance?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, truststore

I have a application used by multiple clients (which one with his/her client certificate). This application is supposed to comunicate with a web service (using the HttpClient) through HTTPS. To authenticate in this web service, it's necessary to provide a client certificate. As said before, each client has a different client certificate and I need to use the certificate of the current client. I have the following code that is doing what is described.

```
X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
};
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyManager[] managers = /* Code that get the current client's KeyManager[] */;

sslcontext.init(managers, trustManager, null);
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext);
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443);

client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
HttpPost post = /* Code that get the POST */ 

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, new BasicHttpContext());
```

Ok, it's working. But there're a lot of threads sending requests to this service. Sometimes it gives me some problem. So, I found lots of people telling that it's better to have just ONE HttpClient per application and that it can be done this way:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

PoolingClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
// Increase max total connection to 200
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
// Increase default max connection per route to 20
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
// Increase max connections for localhost:80 to 50
HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 50);

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

This way I have a HttpClient with a pool of connections. But how do I use this approach and select the client certificate for a specific request? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm gonna try to explain why I'm trying this. We're having problems sometimes. The server stops the communication with the web server and, after sometime, it starts working again. It's important to note that there's a lot of processing done before the call for the webservice. So, there's a pooled Executor that creates threads to do all the processing. When the job is done, this thread creates another thread that communicates with the webservice. So, the first thread join the second with a timeout (thread.join(timeout)). When the first thread wakes up, it interrupts the thread that is trying to communicate with the webservice, if it's not done yet. I'm not the who has implemented this, but it's supposed to give a timeout to the request to complete.
In my development machine, I created a JMeter test that simulates a lot of clients using this service and connected the JConsole to see what was happening. After 300 tasks have been done (some of them failed), the threads created by the pool of the Executor died. But lots of threads has kept alive and they just died after 10 minutes. When I looked the stacktrace, I saw it's related to the HttpClient. Then, I started searching and found people saying that it's better to use only one HttpClient for the whole application, making it pools the connections.
I think that the HttpClient is locking while searching for a port to connect and is being interrupted by the first thread. Then, somehow, it locks for a long time.

EDIT:

This is what I see in the JConsole. This time, I started only 100 tasks and there're 15 threads in this state:

```
Name: Thread-228
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 0

Stack trace: 
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
   - locked java.lang.Object@7c1975
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
   - locked java.lang.Object@16b53a6
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:91)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:692)
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3671.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
br.com.fibonacci.webservice.InvocacaoDeServico$_monteChamada_closure8.doCall(InvocacaoDeServico.groovy:441)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3667.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
br.com.fibonacci.webservice.InvocacaoDeServico$_monteChamada_closure8.call(InvocacaoDeServico.groovy)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3662.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:63)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
br.com.fibonacci.ChamadaComTimeout$_execute_closure1.doCall(ChamadaComTimeout.groovy:19)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3657.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
br.com.fibonacci.ChamadaComTimeout$_execute_closure1.doCall(ChamadaComTimeout.groovy)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3655.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:910)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:355)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: That code is vulnerable to MITM attacks. Don't use trust managers that do nothing like this (in addition `getAcceptedIssuers` should at least return `new X509Certificate[0]`, not `null`). Don't use a host name verifying that allows anything to get through.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm maintaining this software and it was already doing it. I have no experience with SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible as IMO it does not make any sense.
Reusing a connection for plain text makes sense but **not** for an **authenticated encrypted** connection.
Each connection belongs to a user and should terminate according to SSL parameters and not reuse that among users.

Comment: It also barely makes sense to have a single client have access to credentials from multiple users at the same time. (It could make sense for a server that uses a delegated authentication mechanism, I guess.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble with many HttpClients being opened. I verified with JConsole that some threads are locking having some exception inside HttpClient and they keep alive for about 10 minutes until the server kill them. I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281219/best-practice-to-use-httpclient-in-multithreaded-environment that recommends to use only one HttpClient. Isn't there any better solution for multithread?