# Use 4.0 version of httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to update httpclient version in my project.The project was using http 3.1 jar now I need to upgrade 4.0 version.I downloaded repository from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0)

I changed most of the code but stuck on some api and method.I googled much but not able to find the equivalent of that, I am describing below that:

What is the eqvivalent of MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager?

I found PoolingClientConnectionManager for httpClient 4.x but it doesn't exist in 4.0 version.
here is my old codebase for httpversion 3.1

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connMgr = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    m_client = new HttpClient(connMgr);

    /*
     * Maximum concurrent connections that are allowed to a given
     * domain/host
     */
    m_client.getHttpConnectionManager()
            .getParams()
            .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(
                    HostConfiguration.ANY_HOST_CONFIGURATION,
                    maxConcurrentConnections);

    /*
     * 
     * How long to wait before timing out on a http connection
     */
    m_client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams()
            .setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);

    /*
     * How long to wait before timing out on a socket connection
     */
    m_client.getParams().setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like httpclient 4.0 used [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html), which was deprecated in favor of [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html) in version 4.2.

I found this in the following thread: [Best Practice to Use HttpClient in Multithreaded Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281219/best-practice-to-use-httpclient-in-multithreaded-environment)