# org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient multithreading calls crash

Tags: apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-httpclient

Hi all I use apache's httpclient to make restcalls, everything is working fine, When multiple thread are using this method my app crashes.
What is the implementation for this class that is MultithreadSafe.

Here is my code.

```
        httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpMethod method = null;
        method = new GetMethod();

           ... method creation...

        httpClient.executeMethod(method);
        method.releaseConnection();
```

Thanks in advance. Juan

Comment: When you say crashes, do you have any stacktrace? Also, they recommend reusing instances. Also, what pool size have you configured? Maybe also worth taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281219/best-practice-to-use-httpclient-in-multithreaded-environment?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the HttpClient [threading documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html) ?

> To get started one must create an instance of the
>   MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager and give it to an HttpClient. This
>   looks something like:
>
> ```
>       MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = 
>           new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
>       HttpClient client = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
> ```

The issue you're having is quite common when using HttpClient *out-of-the -box*

Comment: thanks a lot Brian. Is there a way to test this concurrency problems properly?