# How is the resource clean up being done in the following Apache HttpClient usage with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

The code that is being referred to is under [this question on codereview forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/http-client-requests-done-right).

When you do this HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(request), r) in the query method, you have used the client to send the HttpRequest.. Don't you need to release / clean up any resources ?

Does the monitor thread's

```
while ((stopRequest = stopSignal.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) == null) {
      // Close expired connections
      cm.closeExpiredConnections();
      // Optionally, close connections that have been idle too long.
      cm.closeIdleConnections(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      // Look at pool stats.
      log.trace("Stats: {}", cm.getTotalStats());
    }
```

suffice to release the connection that is used by the client obtained from the pool.

**A Few Questions :**

- Does this mean that we let the connection expire OR go idle for them to be reclaimed by the pool ?
- What is the difference between expiry and going idle ?
- **How are the physical connections, Connection objects, ConnectionManager objects, HttpClient objects' life cycles maintained and what is the relation between them ?**

Sorry about the amateur questions. I am new to HttpClient.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : I think you can provide the latest updated answer to the question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281219/best-practice-to-use-httpclient-in-multithreaded-environment  - Please check and reply. Your answer would definitely help others.

Answer (score 2):

The primary cleanup happens in the `readResponse` method where `content.close();` and then `response.close();`.

The core of the mechanism is:

```
    // Start a conversation.
    CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(request);
```

`getClient()` pulls a `CloseableHttpClient` from the client pool. This is actually a `Singleton` thread-safe client an so does not need to be tidied up, it manages multiple uses internally.

`execute` executes the request and returns the `CloseableHttpResponse` for parsing and processing. This is cleaned up by calling `close` on it in `readResponse`. Note that it is closed in a `finally` clause to ensure it does not leak.

```
    // Roll out the results
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
      InputStream content = entity.getContent();
```

Within `readResponse` a new `InputStream` is created to gather the content of the response - this is also cleaned properly through closure in a `finally` clause.

The idle thread is only intended for hanging connections left by unexpected events, it is certainly not the primary cleanup mechanism.

Comment: Sure. Will wait for your further updates to this answer. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Small correction: idle connection thread is intended to evict _idle_ connections which might have gone stale (half-closed) while sitting idly in the connection pool.  +1 otherwise.

Comment: @acthota - Details filled out - hope that is sufficient.